# Logic-level MOSFET not varying drain voltage

Tags: led, mosfet, esp8266, logic-level

I have a series of [FQP30N06L logic-level MOSFETs](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FQ/FQP30N06L.pdf) connected to a 3.3V logic controller.  I am feeding the MOSFETs a PWM signal in order to vary the drain voltage, however, I am only experiencing a couple hundred millivolt variation.  The source voltage is connected to a 12.5V supply and on the drain, I see between 12.3-12.5V.  I've attached my schematic below; what am I doing wrong?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: See those diodes in your MOSFET symbols? What do you think they do when the source is pulled up to 12 V and the drain is tied to ground?

Comment: When you measured 12.3 V on the drain (which the schematic shows tied to GND), where were you putting the black lead of your multimeter?

Comment: @The Photon I was measuring ground on the drain of the red (Q1 drain).

Comment: So the difference between the drain and the drain was 12.3 V?

Comment: Yes, the difference was 12.3V

Comment: Between the drain of Q1 and the drain of Q1?

Comment: @Owen - *read* what ThePhoton has written. Read it again.

Comment: Also notice that your schematic shows a signal called `GIPO4` connected to the gate of Q1, but the signal at the controller that is probably supposed to be connected is called `GPIO4`. If you actually built a design from this schematic, you have a floating gate on Q1. If you didn't actually build the circuit from this schematic, how did you build it (breadboard, wire-wrap, ...)?

Comment: Right now I an ESP12-E breakout board and the MOSFETs wired on a breadboard with the MOSFET gates connected to the GPIO via dupont wires through the 220 ohm resistors.

Comment: You appear to be confused about which pin is the drain and which is the source and which way around to wire your MOSFETs.

Comment: @brhans drain->LED cathode, source->GND, gate->GPIO

Comment: Yeah - that's what it should be. But it's not what you've drawn in your schematic, and probably not what you've built (judging by your results & attention to detail).

Comment: @behans Ahh, I do have it correctly on my breadboard.  I've just updated my schematic.  I have the leftmost pin to GPIO, the middle pin to the LED strip, and the rightmost pin to GND.

Comment: You should NEVER breadboard MPU's and MOSFET's. Contact resistance and ground bounce can make them self-oscillate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting it to work in the end after some fiddling around.  I think my issue was that my PWM signal was varying too quickly and my multimeter did not pick up on it.  I figured this out after connecting the gate directly to 5V and 3.3V where I noticed the same voltage on the drain.  I've posted my updated schematic below, which I had been using on my breadboard all along.  I had an error on my original schematic as @brahns pointed out by switching the drain and source.

[image: schematic]